# How to set list with Radio Buttons in Android Auto?

Tags: android, android-radiobutton, android-auto

I am trying to create a list with Radio Buttons as in the following picture:

[Radio Button + Text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TEyoE.png)

What happens is that I'm using the `Row` class from the `androidx.car.app.model package`, and I can't find any option to add a Radio Button (other than adding images or a switch).

With what class could I implement it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To make a list of radio buttons, you must make the list selectable using the [`setOnSelectedListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/car/app/model/ItemList.Builder#setOnSelectedListener(androidx.car.app.model.ItemList.OnSelectedListener)) method of the [`ItemList.Builder`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/car/app/model/ItemList.Builder).

See [this code](https://github.com/android/car-samples/blob/12e4ef5bc1f69c30a56ab8459586cfa20b88b055/car_app_library/showcase/common/src/main/java/androidx/car/app/sample/showcase/common/SelectableListsDemoScreen.java#L108) for an example.